# Turn characters/strings identified by multiple categories into individual strings

Tags: r, string, character

I have a df which categorises movies based on genre. Of course, many movies fall under many categories.
The raw data has these categories identified as one single character, the result is this:

```
unique(netflix_and_disney$genre)
      [1] "Comedy, Drama, Romance"
```

Is there a way to split each individual case, so that when I run the unique() function, I get a result more like:

```
[1] "Comedy", "Drama", "Romance"
```

Comment: `strsplit(netflix_and_disney$genre, ", ")`

Comment: @DanielO + `unlist()`

Comment: I ran this code including the unlist() and got this error code:
  "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: the code essentially turned my df into a df of 1x1 with all individual genres, but removed all the other data. why would this be?